# pdfkit not converting image to pdf

Tags: python, pdfkit

I am using PDFkit with python to convert an html page to pdf. In the html there is only one image tag in body with src pointing to a complete url like:

```
<html>
    <body style="margin: 0px;">
        <img style="-webkit-user-select: none; cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;" src="https://blah.blah.com" height="768">
    </body>
</html>
```

However When I convert html to pdf like this:

```
pdfkit.from_file(file, 'labels.pdf', configuration=config)
```

I get a blank page with a box with border instead of image.

Why is pdfkit not converting image?

I read somewhere that we have to give full image path including domain name. But the image url I am providing is complete. Then what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I quickly tested this and got pdf with image. See if this works without passing configuration `pdfkit.from_file(file, 'labels.pdf')`. If it does, there's something wrong with your configuration. May be you are using configuration instead of options?

Answer (score 10):

**I encoded the image as a string of Base64 data**, following @Manish Gupta's suggestion.  In Python:

```
import base64

def get_image_file_as_base64_data():
    with open(FILEPATH, 'rb') as image_file:
        return base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
```

In my Jinja2 template (I know the question isn't specific to Jinja2, but this is what I'm using):

```
<img src="data:;base64,{{ get_image_file_as_base64_data() }}">
```

Comment: it is more clean way for rendering template inside django backend. thanks!

Comment: To return a string worth use in Html you should use ` base64.b64encode(image_file.read()).decode()`

Comment: just change 'r' to 'rb' in the open() function call -- great answer btw, Josh!

Answer (score 4):

I use the file path instead of the file url in image src, like:

```
<img src="D:/image/path/pircure.png">
```

and it work, maybe you can try it.

Comment: it will fail when environment get changed. so stick to the nomenclature of the language.

Comment: I found a better way. I base64 encoded the image and passed it to the html.

Answer (score 3):

I liked the approach of Adrian Lin.
Though, I am using Django in Docker and the following is working for me just great:

**Python**:

```
from django.template import Context, Template
import pdfkit

template_folder = 'media'
context['media_folder'] = os.path.abspath(template_folder)

template_file = os.path.join(template_folder, 'template.html')
with open( template_file, 'r') as f:
    template = Template(f.read())

html_file = template.render(Context(context))

pdfkit.from_string(html, filename)
```

**Html template**:

```
<img src="{{media_folder}}/my_pic.png">
```

Answer (score 2):

These other answers weren't working for me, but I was able to piece a few answers together from here and other sources and found this solution.

I have a jinja template with the tag:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ img_string }}" width="500px">
```

Then, I pass the template an image as a base64 encoded string by running it through the following function:

```
def image_file_path_to_base64_string(filepath: str) -> str:
  '''
  Takes a filepath and converts the image saved there to its base64 encoding,
  then decodes that into a string.
  '''
  with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
    return base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode()
```

So in the end, ignoring sundry Jinja initializations I have

```
# generate html with base64 encoded string of image
html_string = jinja_template.render(
    img_string=image_file_path_to_base64_string('path/to/img.png'))

# generate pdf
pdfkit.from_string(html_string, 'html.pdf')
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it in a slightly similar way and it smoothly converts the image.

in views:

```
pdf_content = pdfkit.from_string(html_string, False)
```

In template tags:

```
@register.filter
def get_image_file_as_base64_data(CONTRACTOR_LOGO):
    image_bytes = CONTRACTOR_LOGO.read()
    base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(image_bytes)
    base64_string = base64_bytes.decode("ascii")
    return base64_string
```

in template file

```
<img style="height: 35px;" alt="Contractor Logo" src="data:image/png;base64, {{ contractor.logo | get_image_file_as_base64_data }}">
```

Note: Here I am sending the image file to the template tag which processes the image and returns base64_string.

Answer (score 1):

add `enable-local-file-access` to options:

```py
options = {
    "enable-local-file-access": True,
}
pdfkit.from_file(temp_html_file.name, output_pdf.name, options=options, verbose=True)
```

Comment: I tried various methods and was about to give up, but your method solved the problem. I appreciate you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using flask + Jinja2 and the best solution I found is passing the media folder as parameter based on `current_app.config.root_path`:

**In Python code:**

```
...
rendered_template = render_template(template_path, **data, media_folder=str(Path(current_app.config.root_path)/'static'))
...
```

**In HTML:**

```
<img src="{{media_folder}}/img/file_name.png">
```