# Image file can't covert to pdf when using python-pdfkit

Tags: python, django, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit, python-pdfkit

Here is my code

```py
options = {
      "enable-local-file-access": True,
      ...
}
```

```py
pdfkit.from_string(html_file, pdf_file, options=options, ...)
```

since Im using Django template, here is my code to reference that

```py
 <img src="{{ static_root }}{% static '../../target.svg' %}" alt="">
```

I use a local image file in html, It just shows a blank box in pdf output file

I also tried using "base64" to resolve my issue base on this link [pdfkit not converting image to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38329909/pdfkit-not-converting-image-to-pdf)

It doesn't really work to me.

Comment: django generates HTML with URLs for browser which can ask server for images. But `pdfkit` works as normal program which can't send to server request for image and I would rather use normal paths `/full/path/to/file`

Comment: `It doesn't really work to me.` is useless information. Did you get error when you run it? How do you use `base64`? Better show your code.

Comment: Hey, thank you y'all to respond my question. I realized I just can't use .svg format image in this case, and I don't know why exactly, but .png works perfectly to me which resolved my issue.

Comment: do you have this problem when you use PNG in django ?

Comment: as I remeber `PDF` was invented before `SVG` was invented and maybe `PDF` have problem with this format. OR `pdfkit` have problem with this format.

Comment: we can't run your code so we can't test it - and we can't help more.

Comment: Hey, PNG is working good in Django. Like you said, pdfkit might has issue to handle SVG file? Anyway, I can convert it to png as a solution, I wont border this issue for now.

Comment: I don't know if `pillow` can convert `SVG` to `PNG` but I can convert it with tool [imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org) which is also used by python module [wand](https://docs.wand-py.org/)

Answer (score 0):

realized pdfkit doesn't like .svg, I use .png format instead

Answer (score 0):

wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6 (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS) (console) - all ok

```
wkhtmltopdf --enable-local-file-access ./file.html ./file.pdf
```

in python script not so bad too:)

```
options = {'enable-local-file-access': None}

pdfkit.from_file("file.html", "file.pdf", options=options) # all ok!

pdfkit.from_string(html_str,  "file.pdf", options=options) # no images (jpg, png) :(
```